# Reading a column with a list data type

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]})
```

For each row col1 is a list. This can also be seen here:

```
type(df.loc[0]['col1']) # list
```

If I save the data and then reload it each row is now a str:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv',index=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
type(df2.loc[0]['col1']) # str
```

I would like to get the original data format were each row of col1 is a list.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `df.to_pickle('test.pkl')` and then `pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')`?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. One issue is that I already have a really large file that I saved to csv and regenerating it from scratch in order to pickle it would be painful.

Comment: If you check out the [`pandas Performance Considerations`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations) at the very bottom, you can see that reading from and writing to a pickle can be orders of magnitude faster than `.csv` If your files are large and you read and write regularly, switching file formats can be useful. It also serializes python objects, so really a win win IMO.

Comment: Thanks. That benchmark is really useful. I'll definitely start using that functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best way, but still can serve your purpose.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')      
df2['col1']=df2['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[1:len(x)-1].split(',')) 
type(df2.loc[0]['col1']) # list
```

If all the lists are of same length you may replace `len(x)` with that.